# applescript to delete files in applications support directory

Tags: macos, applescript

As part of my uninstaller script, I'd like to delete my app's directory in `~/Application Support/My App Name`.

My uninstaller script is Apple Script. I've tried the following:

```
tell application "Finder" to delete (POSIX file "~/Library/Application Support/My App Name")
```

```
do shell script \"
sudo rm -rf '~/Library/Application Support/My App Name'
\" with administrator privileges
"""
```

But none of these had any effect, my app's Application Support directory remains. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use *System Events* instead of *Finder* for file system operations, then you can freely use posix-style paths, including the tilde.  Then your script needs very little changing:

```
tell application "System Events" to delete the item ¬
        "~/Library/Application Support/My App Name"
```

However, the *System Events* `delete` command mirrors the shell `rm` command, in that it permanently deletes files from the filesystem, without sending them to the trash.

Instead of supplying a hard-coded path to the Application Support folder, you can utilise the *System Events* property of the same name:

```
tell application "System Events" to delete the folder ¬
        "My App Name" in the application support folder
```

---

<sup>**Tip:** There are one or two Finder-specific capabilities that can only be achieved using *Finder*, namely accessing *Finder windows*, getting or setting selected files in *Finder* (by way of the `selection` property or the `select` command), revealing files (using the `reveal` command), and getting the `insertion location` property.  But other than when you need to invoke one of these, it's best to avoid *Finder* as it's slow, buggy (so is *System Events*, but not as much), it doesn't handle posix-style paths, and it blocks *Finder* during any and all operations (and, since it's slow, it blocks for a potentially long time, or times-out altogether meaning you have to restart *Finder*).  Even when invoking one of the *Finder*-specific functions, I typically have it perform literally that one task, making sure it returns either `alias` class file referneces, or plain text file paths (HFS-style colon-delimited paths are fine), rather than Finder file references.  *System Events* can utilise `alias` references as well as HFS-style file paths.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that the tilde is not expanded.

In the user folder you don't need *administrator privileges*. Just get the folder with a relative path.

```
set applicationSupportFolder to path to application support folder from user domain
tell application "Finder" to delete folder "My App Name" of applicationSupportFolder
```